# Can Roslyn recognize all tokens that correspond to a given variable?

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis

I am trying to use Roslyn to determine information about objects being added to a collection.  The general pattern of the code is that an IList is passed in to a method (which I am able to get the MethodDeclarationSytax for) and then a number of objects are added to that collection.  I need to be able to tell where the Add method is being called on the passed in collection, which is always the only parameter passed to the method.

I have only been able to figure out how to do this on string matching to tokens rather than being able to directly recognize that a given token is the same variable based on scope.

How can I get information out of Roslyn that will indicate that the tokens are, in fact, actually references to the same variable based on scope?  Is there an option for this in the semantic view?  Is string comparison and manual scope checking the only option available to me?

```
public void AddColumns(IList<Column> columns)
{
    Column newColumn = new Column("something");
    columns.Add(newColumn);

    newColumn = new Column("somethingElse");
    columns.Add(newColumn);

    Column anotherNewColumn = new Column("something else");
    anotherNewColumn.MakeSomeChanges("123");
    columns.Add(anotherNewColumn );
}
```

In this code for example, I have the MethodDeclarationSyntax for AddColumns.  I need to be able to identify lines 4, 7 and 11 as being places where the Add is happening and, preferably, will further need to determine where newColumn and anotherNewColumn come from (lines 3, 6 and 9).

I can fall back to string based checking if I have to, but I'm worried about missing cases that don't match what I expect since there are also examples where methods are used in adding columns, so it will get really complicated really fast.

Comment: Just one suggestion: you'll find it easier to research this sort of thing searching with the right name - Roslyn not Rosalyn. I understand it's really easy to make typos for product names like this; I'm not trying to criticize. (The number of times I've looked at "lambda" and puzzled over whether the 'b' belongs there.)

Comment: As for the actual question - I'm not *sure* whether it does that sort of data flow analysis. It might help others to grok your question if you give a concrete example of the kind of code you're analyzing though.

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks for the edit.  I even knew I'd been misspelling it but still haven't gotten in through my head and missed that I slipped back in to the wrong spelling again.  Thanks for the catch.  I'll try to mock up a sample to make it more clear.  I'm a bit worried it can't do it as well, but it seems odd that it wouldn't since it's working from a similar tree to what the compiler uses if my understanding is correct.

Comment: You'd definitely be able to find all uses of the *symbol* - but keeping track of all the variables that definitely (or potentially?) have the same value could be very tricky, and isn't generally required for a compiler. (I'm thinking about `var otherList = list; otherList.Add(...)`. If you don't need that, it should be much simpler. Look up the `ISymbol` for the invocation target.)

Comment: Tracking assignments and different variables that point to the same value is generally difficult, and doesn't come with Roslyn out of the box. The data flow analysis engine that we implemented in [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/) does track values. It's [open source](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/master/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/src/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/Helpers/SymbolicExecution/ExplodedGraph.cs), so you could have a look if you need something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the SemanticModel API that you can get from a Compilation object for a specific SyntaxTree that is part of the compilation. With the SemanticModel you can get the symbols referenced at specific points in the source, by calling GetSymbolInfo for the expression for the parameter name (probably an IdentifierNameSyntax).